# Как растянуть input на всю ширину родителя?

Tags: html, css

Есть у меня форма и wrapper.
Даю wrapper-у display:flex;
Даю form-е max-width: 480px;
и input-ам даю width:100% но инпуты не растягивается на всю ширину.

```
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Стили

```
div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

form {
  max-width: 480px;
  background-color: blue;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Можно без flex-grow: 1

Comment: Вы хотите невозможного. Ширина родителя зависит от ширины его потомков (потому что вы сделали flex), а вы пытаетесь сделать ширину потомка зависимым от ширины родителя — вполне логично, что от такого замкнутого цикла зависимостей получается что попало

Comment: max-width: никак невозможно растянуть?

Comment: max-width не предназначен никого никуда растягивать, он просто задаёт максимальную возможную ширину элемента

Comment: зачем задавать форм  max-width: 480px; в пикселях? если он не должен занимать больше какого то места, укажите ему ширину в vw например. типа width: 40vw, где он занимает 40% экрана. инпуты со 100% вместе с ним будут тянуться. на маленькие экраны через медиа другие настройки и готово

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если вам нужно растянуть `input` на всю ширину `div`'а то уберите `max-width` и используйте используется просто `width` со значением `100%`.

`max-width` не задает ширину компонента, а указывает на максимальное допустимое значение для него.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  background-color: red;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

А если `input` нужно растянуть на всю ширину `form` то все у вас работает правильно, просто посмотрите страницу через `DevTools` в браузере